# What exactly happens when we do an "ionic cordova build android"?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I understand that a folder - \platform\android gets created.

I want to understand from point of view of config.xml, package.json, package-lock.json, and other important files; how are these files used or affected as part of the build process.

Assuming the project is downloaded from version control system, with just the code. No plugins folder, no platform folder, no modules folder. What exactly happens when we do an "ionic cordova build android"? Which file controls or is inferred by ionic cordova to install the plugins?

The reason for asking this question is I faced lot of difficulties when resolving plugin dependency issues which I tried to resolve by editing the plugin version in the config.xml file, but it got overwritten to original value after running the build command. Similarly the package.json file. The only thing that helped me was to change the plugin version \platform\android\project.properties file OR \plugin\plugin-name\plugin.xml file (under preference section). But these solutions are not good since these files are not checkedin into version control so every developer will have to make these amendments. Finally gradle (cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) was the right solution to align the versions. **So I want to understand the whole build process at a high-level**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things which happens while you build for Android platform.

- Ionic-app-scripts builds a web project using your code and which gets populated under **/www** folder.
- Now the plugins listed in **config.xml** will get downloaded from their source repo and an android project will be created under **/platforms**. **/plugins** will have a copy of plugin resources which are downloaded from their sources.
- The Android Project created will be a WebView project containing only one Main Java file called as MainActivity.java which loads the app ( Web App created by ionic-app-scripts ) in webview.

Here **package.json** and **package-lock.json** are the dependency managers which will manage the project dependencies during installation of node modules.

Comment: But I notice that the config.xml file itself gets changed was build command is running

Comment: @variable Any changes, in particular, you are referring to?

Comment: For example - if you delete the modules, platform and plugins folder from your project and run "ionic cordova build android", you will notice that the config.xml file contents are re-ordered. It appears as though the file is changing.

Comment: Yeah that's the expected behavior as package.json will try to modify the contents of config.xml, depending on the dependencies entries declared in package.json